# Can't open JSP file with Eclipse Indigo

Tags: eclipse, jsp

I have newly installed eclipse indigo (version 3.8.1). When I try to open a .JSP file it shows error code below. How to fix it?

Error message:

> Could not open the editor: The editor class could not be instantiated. This usually indicates a missing no-arg constructor or that the editor's class name was mistyped in plugin.xml.

Comment: You have *newly* installed a very *old* version. Try it again with the current one, making sure you're installing it properly ( https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_FAQ#How_do_I_install_WTP.3F assuming you're using the tools from eclipse.org) and if it also fails, get the detailed log output ( https://wiki.eclipse.org/IRC_FAQ#Where_are_Eclipse.27s_log_files_located.3F ) and include it in the question.

Comment: fix title and error message formatting

Comment: I've installed it in Linux OS. I am not getting where I am missing.